# Custom keyboard for uiwebview for ipad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am working on an iPad app which works in `UIWebView`, and I want to use a custom keyboard that contains only numbers (0-9) like iPhone numpad for some of the input fields.

Any suggestions or code sample please.

Comment: How are any of the 7 Apple keyboards not meeting your needs?

Comment: Probably in the same way that Apple doesn't use it's own standard keyboards for its own applications.  IE Calculator

Answer (score 0):

You can make the UIWebView display the number pad keyboard by setting the attribute in the input tag.

```
<input type="number" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i need only 12 keys Keypad with 0-9,clear and close keys.for ipad if i set input type="number" other than 0-9 i will get other keys like (),/,:,$,& etc..which i dont want it should be exclusive numpad like one which iphone numpad has.i made custom keyboard in uiview but unable to call that uiview for input feilds in uiwebView.For native appliction i can able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Apple already has a numeric keyboard that you can use.

You can programmatically set it using:

```
input type="number"
```

You can also set it through the Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i need only 12 keys Keypad with 0-9,clear and close keys.for ipad if i set input type="number" other than 0-9 i will get other keys like (),/,:,$,& etc..which i dont want it should be exclusive numpad like one which iphone numpad has.i made custom keyboard in uiview but unable to call that uiview for input feilds in uiwebView.For native appliction i can able to do that.